# How to debug a crashing JavaFX program?

Tags: javafx, media

I'm working on a college project and we've been asked to choose a program to make so I chose to work on teaching kids their ABC's. But suddenly my project crashed when I added the media and I tried to find out why but it's no use.

```
package project;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Project extends Application {

    private String[] letters = {"A", "B", "C",
            "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
            "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    private ImageView[] ImageViews = {
            new ImageView("a.jpg"),
            new ImageView("b.jpg"),
            new ImageView("c.jpg"),
            new ImageView("d.jpg"),
            new ImageView("e.jpg"),
            new ImageView("f.jpg"),
            new ImageView("g.jpg"),
            new ImageView("h.jpg"),
            new ImageView("i.jpg"),
            new ImageView("j.jpg"),
            new ImageView("k.jpg"),
            new ImageView("l.jpg"),
            new ImageView("m.jpg"),
            new ImageView("n.jpg"),
            new ImageView("o.jpg"),
            new ImageView("p.jpg"),
            new ImageView("q.jpg"),
            new ImageView("r.jpg"),
            new ImageView("s.jpg"),
            new ImageView("t.jpg"),
            new ImageView("u.jpg"),
            new ImageView("v.jpg"),
            new ImageView("w.jpg"),
            new ImageView("x.jpg"),
            new ImageView("y.jpg"),
            new ImageView("z.jpg")    
    };

    protected MediaView[] sound = {
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("a.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("b.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("c.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("d.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("e.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("f.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("g.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("h.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("i.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("j.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("k.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("l.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("m.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("n.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("o.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("p.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("q.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("r.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("s.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("t.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("u.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("v.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("w.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("x.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("y.mp3"))),
            new MediaView(new MediaPlayer(new Media("z.mp3")))
    };

    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> l = new ListView<>
                (FXCollections.observableArrayList(letters));
        l.setPrefSize(300, 700);
        l.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        FlowPane imagePane = new FlowPane(20, 20);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setLeft(new ScrollPane(l));
        pane.setCenter(imagePane);

        l.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                ov -> {
                    imagePane.getChildren().clear();
                    for (Integer i : l.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
                        imagePane.getChildren().add(ImageViews[i]);
                    }
                });

        ListView<String> le = new ListView<>
                (FXCollections.observableArrayList(letters));
        le.setPrefSize(300, 700);
        le.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        FlowPane soundpane = new FlowPane(10, 10);
        pane.setCenter(soundpane);
        pane.setRight(new ScrollPane(le));

        l.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                ov -> {
                    soundpane.getChildren().clear();
                    for (Integer i : l.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
                        soundpane.getChildren().add(sound[i]);
                    }
                });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Letters");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "suddenly my project crushed" <= what does this mean?  It is hard for somebody to help you when it is not clear what you need help with.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake but netbeans keep telling that there is some logic error with the mediaview array and I couldn't fix it hope you understand what I'm saying 

Comment: "there is some logic error with the mediaview array" - any chance you could add the exact error into your question?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would just be processing power. Try speech synthesis instead of 26 audio files

Comment: If speech synthesis didn't solve the issue, just try trimming your code down and follow principles of Clean Code. DRY etc.